# Force leaflet to use a fixed tile zoom level

Tags: javascript, maps, zooming, leaflet, tile

I want leaflet to just use the tiles zoomed to level 20 and disregard the lower zoom level tiles.

Is there any way to make Leaflet use chosen zoom level no matter how much the map is actually zoomed?

I thought that zIndex option of TileLayer would do it but it doesn't seem to do anything (I'm not sure what it's supposed to do).

**To say it another way:**
I want to be able to zoom still and force Leaflet to use 4 tiles to form one tile of a lower zoom level.

Is the better solution is to just combine the tiles beforehand and then feed those combined tiles to leaflet?

Comment: did you find any solution ?